# Core Plot scatter chart scrolls beyond x-axis in negative direction

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to set up a graph which has scrolling enabled in the positive quadrant. The problem here is on scrolling the graph starts overlapping with the y-axis labels! As shown in the screenshot below. Any help would be really appreciated. I am using the following code to set up the global range of the plot.

```
plotSpace.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([xAxisPlots count]*2)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(maxValue*GLOBAL_AXIS_RATIO)];
```

[image: Image shows the error marked with yellow color annotation]

```
-(void)configureGraph
{
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
[graph setPaddingLeft:5.0f];
// 2 - Set graph title
//    NSString *title = graphTitle;
//    graph.title = title;
// 3 - Create and set text style
CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
// 4 - Set padding for plot area
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:32.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:45.0f];
// 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
```

}

and the axis plot is this:

```
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5f;
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
// 2 - Get axis set
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
// 3 - Configure x-axis
CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
x.title = @"Days";
x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
x.titleOffset = 25.0f;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
//4 - Configure y axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y.title = yAxisTitle;
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -10.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = 0.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
```

Comment: Plots are clipped to the "plot area". How are the graph and axes set up? Do you have padding on the graph and/or plot area frame?

Comment: @EricSkroch yes i do have a padding for the plot. In case I remove the padding, my y axis labels and titles start disappearing. Though, yes the plot starts behaving properly.

Comment: Can you post the graph and axis setup code?

Comment: @EricSkroch : Here, i have adde the code for graph an axis setup.

Comment: I just tried your setup code in one of the Core Plot example apps. It worked as expected. You've got something else going on in your app. You only have one graph with three plots, right?

Comment: yes you are right @EricSkroch, i have just one graph with three plots in it. How many values for the plots did you check with. This error starts happening when the no of values become more, i.e while scrolling. Initially it starts right but the moment i start scrolling it starts behaving like the image i have posted above.

Comment: The axes are configured to be at the edges of the plot area and the plots should be clipped to the plot area. Given only the code you posted, I don't see how this should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop Scrolling plotspace beyond negative values.
Try this one : 
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

plotSpace.globalYRange = [plotSpace yRange];